# How to center flexbox container itself?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to flexbox and I am having an issue. I am trying to center a flexbox container with respect to the webpage yet it is not working; Here is my syntax:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>hello></h1>
  <h1>world></h1>
</div>
```

can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include align-items: center for the flexbox.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>hello></h1>
  <h1>world></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I want to center it both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: I adjusted the code to center both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @Emma To center horizontally and vertically, check mine or Michael's answer, they both do that, ....but using absolute positioning is a really bad idea. Keep the accept if you want, just don't go down that road

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the flex container some height, or it defaults to `height: auto` (content height).

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;  /* vertical alignment */
  align-items: center;      /* horizontal alignment */
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

h1 { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>hello></h1>
  <h1>world></h1>
</div>
```

If your goal is to actually center the flex container on the page, then use the same rules you have in `#container` on the parent (in this case, that would be the `body` element).